# Extracting data from table into array, then reprinting onto new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very heavy Excel table (roughly 65,000 lines and 7 columns) that I want to extract, piece-by-piece, onto different worksheets. I've started the program and it seems to run fine, but it always stops the recopying at line 1771, despite me not seeing any glaring errors in the code. The recopying should go to at least line 3500. If I remove the If statement and consolidate the 2 For Loops into 1 For Loop, it still stops at line 1771. Are arrays limited in terms of storage?

```
Sub extract_collar()

Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim cell As Range
Dim x As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myTable = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FullCarriers").ListObjects("CarrierTable")

For i = 1 To 2

    TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(i)

    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        If Mid(myArray(x), 13, 2) = "01" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Collar").Cells(x + 1, i) = myArray(x)
        End If

    Next x

Next i

For i = 3 To 7

    TempArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Columns(i)

    myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)

    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Collar").Cells(x + 1, i) = myArray(x)
    Next x

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The size limit for `Transpose` is around the size of your data, so I'd avoid using transpose altogether if you can.  It's not clear why you use Transpose here though?  You can just as easily loop over `TempArray` without transposing it.    It's not clear what your rules are for copying the data - are you trying to filter the table down to records where Col1 or Col2 have "01" at position 13?

Comment: Thanks Tim. How exactly would you loop through TempArray? Your assumption is correct, the point of the loop is to extract only the rows where there is a "01" at position 13 in column 1

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly:

```
Sub extract_collar()

    Dim inArray As Variant, outArray As Variant
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Long, i As Long, c As Long, cols As Long

    Set myTable = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FullCarriers").ListObjects("CarrierTable")

    inArray = myTable.DataBodyRange.Value 'get all the data
    ReDim outArray(1 To UBound(inArray, 1), 1 To cols) 'size the output array
    cols = UBound(inArray, 2)             'how many columns

    x = 0
    'loop over the data and check if we need the row
    For i = 1 To UBound(inArray, 1)
        If Mid(inArray(i, 1), 13, 2) = "01" Or Mid(inArray(i, 2), 13, 2) = "01" Then           
            x = x + 1 'increment "row" in output array
            'copy the row to the "out" array
            For c = 1 To cols 
                outArray(x, c) = inArray(i, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next

    'dump the results to a worksheet
    If x > 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Collar").Range("A2").Resize(x, cols).Value = outArray
    End If

End Sub
```